# Outlooks preview pane changed to being cramped with large margins

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My Outlook preview pane looks like: 
 [image]

I don't know what changed, but it used to have a nice layout showing the sender, subject, and some of the email. I already tried resetting the view, and signing in and out.

I also discovered that only this folder is affected and my other folders are the normal; this is also the only folder that has the following sorting header, so I think that has something to do with it: 
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by first going to a 'working' folder and then going to the View -> Change View -> Apply Current View to Other Folders. I then checked *all* my folders and had the same view style be applied to them.

This along didn't change anything. I had to open another window of Outlook to see the chance. Perhaps restarting would have implemented the change as well.

Answer (score 1):

Great to see that you've already fixed the issue.

Additionally, in case you encounter any issues related to Outlook views in the future, you can try resetting the views in Outlook using steps below. This can resolve view issues in most cases:

1. Close Outlook.
2. Go to Start menu > Run (or Windows key + R) and type **Outlook.exe /cleanviews** then click OK.

[image]